# Unable to fetch data onto a dynamic page in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a dynamic page in `Nextjs` app, but continue to get an error:

```
./somepage/[id].js (20:25) @ map
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

So basically what I did to recreate the issue was
I set up a dynamic page `[id].js` and tried fetching data from a helper file using getStaticProps and getStaticPaths as shown below:

```
// "./somepage/[id].js"

import {postData} from "./lib/helper"


function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function Post({  posts }) {
 
  console.log(posts); //is "undefined".
  console.log(postData) // logs out the data successfully
  return (
    <>
     {posts.map((post) =>{
       <div key = {post.id}>
        Hello {post.author}, This is your title: {post.title}
       </div>
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const posts = postData(id);

  const paths = posts.map((item) => {
    params: {
      id: item.id.toString();
    }
    return {
      paths,
      fallback: false,
    };
  });
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const posts = postData();

  console.log(posts); //Logs nothing to the console
  return {
    props: { posts }, //This prop `posts` renders as undefined on the page.
  };
}
```

The helper file is a function that returns an array of objects, and filters through the array if the array `id` matches the id from the params as shown below:

```
// "./lib/helper.js"

export function postData(id) {
const data = [{
...
...
}]

if(id){
return data.filter((item) => {
   return item.id === id;
});
}

return data;

}
```

The issue I am having is that if I console log data from the helper file from within `getStaticProps` as shown above, I don't get anything back in the console... nothing, but get the above error in the browser. However, logging `postData`  (from the `helper.js` file) inside of the dynamic page itself returns data as expected, but logging the prop `posts` that I passed in the `getStaticProps` comes out as `undefined` . My version of NextJs is `v.13`.. could the version be the reason why i couldn't pass data as props onto the page?

Comment: As you are using `v.13`, are you using the `app` folder for your pages ?

Comment: @OneQ - No, i recently just upgraded to v.13. This is what my file structure looks like: https://ibb.co/KLhcKqd

Comment: I don't know if it is the reason but it seems you mixed up between getStaticPaths and getStaticProps, see [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-false)

Comment: @OneQ - Thanks for the resource. I'll read up on it now.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is supposed to be something like that :

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = postData();

  const paths = posts.map((item) => {
    params: {
      id: item.id.toString();
    }
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const posts = postData(id);

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt response. Very much appreciated. I tried replicating that code you wrote above into mine to see if yours might, but still got the same "undefined" error. Still going through the NextJs docs to see if i missed anything with the recent upgrade